# Quadrilaterals and figures

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-software

$ABC$ is a triangle in which $L$ is the midpoint of $AB$ and $N$ is a point on $AC$ such that $AN =2CN$. A line thought $L$ parallel to $BN$ meets $AC$ at $M$ prove that $AM=CN$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Also, please explain your tag choice and be consistent in your choice for letters (lowercase/uppercase).

Answer (score 0):

By construction the triangles $ALM$ and $ABN$ are similar  and $2AL=AB$, so we have also $2AM=AN$ and, since $AN=2CN$ we have $2AM=2CN \Rightarrow AM=CN$

[image]